# XML deserialization with JMS Serializer

Tags: php, xml, symfony, serialization, jms-serializer

I am trying to deserialize this very simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <namespace>foo</namespace>
    <resource>bar</resource>
    <description>baz</description>
    <arguments>
        <argument>
            <name>foo</name>
            <type>string</type>
            <description>foo</description>
        </argument>
        <argument>
            <name>bar</name>
            <type>string</type>
            <description>bar</description>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</root>
```

No matter what I try I can not deserialize arguments element into `array` or `ArrayCollection` or any kind of collection as the array always ends up empty.

```
/**
 * @Type("array<Model\Argument>")
 */
private $arguments;

/**
 * @Type("ArrayCollection<Model\Argument>")
 */
private $arguments;
```

Both end up as empty array. So I tried creating a separate object for arguments

Thus the original property ends up as

```
/**
 * @Type("Model\Arguments")
 */
private $arguments;
```

and the class

```
class Arguments {
    /**
     * @Type("array<App\Blueprint\Model\Argument>")
     */
    private $arguments;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getArguments() {
        return $this->arguments;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $arguments
     */
    public function setArguments($arguments) {
        $this->arguments = $arguments;
    }
}
```

the array is still empty. But, when I change the type to `@Type("App\Blueprint\Model\Argument")` I will get the correct object, though only the first one.

When I try to register a deserialization handler I am unable to modify it because it comes as `SimpleXmlElement` and then I will get `It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties` warning...

**EDIT**

For now I managed to solve it in a stupid way:

```
$registry->registerHandler(
    'deserialization',
    'Model\Arguments',
    'xml',
    function(XmlDeserializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, DeserializationContext $context) {
        $arguments = [];
        foreach($data->children() as $child) {
            $arguments[] = SerializerBuilder::create()
                ->build()
                ->deserialize($child->asXML(), 'Model\Argument', 'xml');
        }

        return $arguments;
    }
);
```

Just leaving it out here if someone has a **better** solution.

Comment: Please don't put your answer into the question, make it an answer below it (even if not perfect). You can leave the question open to signal that you're still looking for an answer. -- Or alternatively update the question and make clear in which way your "working" code is insufficient to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were quite close. You have to define two separate classes.

```
/**
 * @Type("Model\Arguments")
 */
public $arguments;
```

```
/**
 * @Type("array<Model\Argument>")
 * @XmlList(inline = true, entry = "argument")
 */
public $argument;
```

Note the `@XmlList` property in the `Argument` class. You can remove the getter and setter too!

Comment: "inline = true"  flag is quite important!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, but not sure this is the way:

My XML:

```
<activityData>
    <count>1</count>
    <facts>
        <fact>
            <dateTime year="2016" month="11" day="14" hour="0" minute="0" second="0" />
            <channel>Administrator</channel>
            <count>1</count>
        </fact>
    </facts>
</activityData>
```

And so my Models:

1.

```
class ActivityData
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|ActivityDataFact[]
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Model\ActivityDataFact>")
     * @Serializer\XmlList(entry="fact")
     */
    private $facts;
    ...
}
```

2.

```
class ActivityDataFact
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("AppBundle\Model\DateTime")
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("dateTime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     */
    private $channel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     */
    private $count;
    ...
}
```

3.

```
class DateTime
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $year = 1970;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $month = 1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $day = 1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $hour = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $minute = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute()
     */
    private $second = 0;
    ...
}
```